# Getting 403 after multiple sucessful requests

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been scraping some real estate pages and hit a wall with one particular website. It started while trying to scrape phone numbers behind JavaScript onclick event. I don't really know too much about JS but from I can tell this is somehow intertwined with displaying ads.

After some closer inspection I've found out this json data on each page:

```
"data": {
            "advert": {
                "...,
                    "phoneObj":[ {
                        "phone": "735", "phoneCode": "173-28-189-69-82-145-233-192-109-58-19-5-226-110-115-225-135-77-50-22-83-36-187-139-85-8-219-95-87-164-33-33-139-78-248-201"
                    }
}
```

Playing around with Web Dev Tools I've determined that this 'phoneCode' is used to get the real phone number by passing its value to the special API URL. I scraped phoneCode, made another request with this special URL and..

Everything worked!

Unfortunately.. After a few sucessful requests I've started recieving 403 errors:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.host.com/frontera/api/item/owner/phone/173-28-189-69-82-145-233-192-109-58-19-5-226-110-115-225-135-77-50-22-83-36-187-139-85-8-219-95-87-164-33-33-139-78-248-201" on this server.

Reference #18.97645e68.1577009665.1a1da860
```

I'm not trying to be very fast while scraping those pages and I don't really think this is because there are low limits on requests. I've opened a bunch of windows using browser and tried clicking those manually and didn't get any problems whatsoever.

My first thought was that it has to do with proper sessions so I've immediately started tinkering with requests.Session() for cookie persistence and more custom headers:

```py
header = {
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'Accept-Language': 'pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
           'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           'Host': 'www.host.com',
           'Pragma': 'no-cache'
          }
```

But this doesn't really help at all. Is there anything I can try to do in order to better pinpoint what is the problem?

Comment: mind to share the url ?

Comment: https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/mieszkanie-4pok-77m2-kety-okazja-atrakcyjna-cena-ID43k0v.html#ab04badaa0 - site is in my language and the data I want to scrape is on a button called 'Wyświetl numer'

Comment: something like that https://repl.it/@AmericanY/test

Answer (score 2):

Basically the `API` is protected with `AkamaiGHost` which is well known firewall.

If you are browsing the `API` via the browser, it's will leave you to do whatever you want without any kind of block.

Once you call the webpage via code, it's will allow you once or more, but once it's analyze your connection, It's will block your IP-Address. so you will need to use `tor`

[image]

Here's a solution:

```
import requests
import time

headers = {'Cookie': 'Cookie: _csrf=nnukVQ2___D88BVt_3GzfUDG; b4da1ddd423e4e8c32114620d61bbfb1=0bfd4455bf8032a1e5e62a2b2db2ca85; bm_sz=5167FDE07330E3099013E268D18AFB4A~YAAQHeF6XED5n3NuAQAAoV5mLQb4rWWWvSkll4rpV5LNOx8bW8lYWVGiw+SKyXZCLJjazkuhzG5U9GpJexyQW4kSullpdq9N7ImTrLC07uFTnoDvyWAcmsXiAtPxUSoxK5ZCSF9xrcr/ZSBrV4ZC3uHuLjryXNfrhaQdQdB1f5gFz+1STW38EPK8TDffNZg=; _abck=68E27962FFDDB95297DAEE8A49E6E038~0~YAAQZ3JlX9+7an5uAQAAYaHaLQOfSeBfhlHt3FQ0LuHf1ZoysOC4RkdU3rtfAAvweF3Ovx8R2/+0IdpC6JNOrX+W/f4QdPA6R31aTAVu/WdgxSNxL5HUQyMqQG1CV1NarTEIramfKxO8++LIpFwfZ2KanBQZbodULrgJAB69ID1tzBz+RMAeBUom/MXsMID9SxRy95qp1lQF+RBxl8t4XlZJF0+2FxqdYEDrlsl2RxO/yqxhn5Z/Xb13c9gnQMn2036VVMhcZVlA2i6n1XppqFyLBoymiMeswoejjYIjRsTexO0jNuvg1LTcRglGn9Umde2l0mls~-1~-1~-1; onap=16f2d666288x105b1c23-3-16f2dd863cfx6b41b522-5-1577024110; ldTd=true; _gcl_au=1.1.1963230701.1577014683; lqstatus=1577022670|16f2dd863cfx6b41b522|gre-9806; laquesis=gre-10591@b#gre-9806@b; laquesisff=; _ga=GA1.2.38751210.1577014684; _gid=GA1.2.543658842.1577014684; __gads=ID=9053a074379a671c-22d104a743a50087:T=1577014685:S=ALNI_MaJQJ-d6rutVuf7LnxOXmGIR03RoA; __gfp_64b=9c7FPwH7yWthkZRHZr3Y4Z0rh6LMYCLWXZPKlTLdINP.a7; PHPSESSID=4dea16ddf9b53cc9374c4e9033cf62a9; mobile_default=desktop; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1577015678908r0.8964587898345969; lastCatType=101; cookieBarSeen=true; ak_bmsc=6029E960D640205FDEA262145E90C8B65F657267692E0000C972FF5DA7317F36~plNg4UFj14Rs42ExadiFOY0WPsw4RYaVN1W8pQRWgKVubwFxZ4i2E/x+XeH/ae7m3d3fxkGLQG32M7Yc6KatTpznk2ydv7RHJ0WVcaitQBOkOMldJBO36S8oNEl/zrXF3DmMLKg/5A1uOlTPtxjjuIg2baCJZa/9plv2nBg5U+sKZL/VwtKFWJ0QFFi3vJqotOovcwY2BtNel+GVx86sBFeBSxDIbcs7mk9KaoODLqU6IvrZCksH2qM9/uxonw9oZz; bm_sv=B875EC57E094201C119B399A54AB5B08~x4qQoaVc7K+pGqLxOHNEbMgykyIKaofv8b6aP/lHqsuoqKLZxD23NY1uv0r0qOEpWbMTXpL7e5Oj51Ll+GlJ5uuSVZ+/0SbWYqWXHaSKzIL5x0+v7p4ZYJIQBwHCIhMMq4sXjBuf5HRlmeJN4pTvqDjHx3dYDlNbf/6ktsqdsik=; _gat_clientNinja=1'}

for item in range(10):
  r = requests.get("https://www.otodom.pl/frontera/api/item/owner/phone/154-147-95-63-124-231-56-151-181-24-172-166-153-110-202-140-185-214-191-162-155-200-255-142-82-184-41-75-23-189-204-95-97-210-122-115", headers=headers)
  print(r.text)
  time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: How do you generate that cookie? Running this example imidiately gave me 403 error.

Comment: give it a try after 1 minute from now, actually it's the cookies which the API taken before giving a response.

Comment: Ok, gave it a minute and it did run. Unfortunately it stoped after 5-6 requests. Ech I suppose that I'll have to use that tor thingy to scrape that. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting an API that is probably not intended for external consumption, at least not the way you're using it. `403 Forbidden` means that you have explicitly been denied the request. Most likely, someone saw your requests and actively blacklisted you, or an adaptive firewall has blocked you.

Comment: I think you are right with the intended use of that API. I've provided a link in the comment - Do you mind looking at it?

Comment: To be frank, looking at it isn't going to accomplish much. 403 errors come from the company that runs the API, so I suspect you'd need to contact them for help.

Comment: @asthasr I've just checked and the `OP` is right, the API will blocking the requests automatically if it's done several times.

Comment: So there is no way to scrap that data? I don't get then why when done manually everything is working fine. I've opened 20 pages and clicked those 20 buttons one after another in like 10 seconds (faster than my acctual script) and everything seems to be working as expected. The only way I can reproduce this error in my browser is when trying to use the phoneCode in different session accessing through the API link. Maybe trying selenium will do the trick?

Comment: @gaxx you just need to use `tor`

Comment: I'll use it if there isn't any other way.. I've dealt with it in the past and it wasn't that great of an experience

Comment: @gaxx are you going to loop over many webpages ? if yes, do you have specific number ?

Comment: I'd like to loop over 72 pages per scheduled event which would be fired around 5/10 minutes I think